# trim() doesn't work as expected in a map closure

Tags: dart

the printed list01 is ["here now", "how "], the whitespace beside "how" wasn't trimmed. Why trim() doens't work here as expected.

````
main() {
    var str='''we are "here now" but "how " you got''';
    var list=aaa(str);
}
aaa(String str){
  final reg00 = RegExp(r'''(".+?")''');
   var list01=reg00.allMatches(str).map((m)=>m[0]?.trim()).toList();
   print(list01);
}```
````

Comment: Because you are calling `.trim()` on the string `'"how "'` not `'how '`. The string is not trimmed because it does not end with a whitespace character, it ends with a quotation character.

Answer (score 0):

As mmcdon20 said I'm calling .trim() on the string '"how "' not 'how '
thanks, problem solved.